# Why is the outer measure of the set of irrational numbers in the interval [0,1] equal to 1?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

Just learned Lebesgue outer measure from Royden's Real Analysis.

Let me give my proof. First, let $A$ be the set of irrational numbers in [0,1]. So $A\subset [0,1]\Rightarrow m^*(A)\le m^*([0,1])=1$.

Then I want to show $m^*(A)\ge 1$ by using $\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k)\le m^*(A)+\epsilon$. $\{I_k\}_k$ covers $A$, then add $I_0$ to this collection. $[0,1]\subset I_0$. So

$l(I_0)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k)\le m^*(A)+\epsilon\Rightarrow m^*(A)\ge l(I_0)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k)-\epsilon\ge 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k)-\epsilon$

We can always choose a small enough $\epsilon>0$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k)-\epsilon>0$. Therefore, $m^*(A)=1$.

Comment: Why is "the" outer measure.... You should say, why is an "outer" measure of.... Unless you are very specific what sort of outer measure you are using, it's NOT obvious

Comment: @Squirtle I disagree, we're talking about the real line, the obvious choice of measure is the Lebesgue measure and the obvious choice of outer measure is the Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: If $I_0\supset [0,1]$ then $l(I_0)\geq 1$ so $l(I_0)+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(I_i)\geq 1+m^*(A),$ and in fact $1+m^*(A)=2. $

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rational numbers has measure zero, so $\mathbb{Q}\in \mathcal{M}(\lambda^*)$. Then

\begin{align}\,1=\lambda^*([0,1])=\lambda^*([0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q})+\lambda^*([0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q})=0+\lambda^*([0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q})\end{align}

i.e., $1=\lambda^*([0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q})$.
$~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 11):

What you know is that $\sum_k l(I_k) \le m^*(A) + \epsilon$ for **some** sequence of intervals covering $A$. You've got $l(I_0) \ge 1$ but only add it to the left-hand side of the inequality so your solution is in error.

Do you know that $m^*([0,1]) = 1$ and $m^*(rationals) = 0$? If so use subadditivity and monotonicity: $$m^*([0,1]) \le m^*(rationals) + m^*(irrationals) = m^*(irrationals) \le m^*([0,1])$$ so that $$m^*(irrationals) = m^*([0,1]) = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks! Yes! I know $m^*(rationals)=0$ because the set of rationals is countable. I made the problem more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

First we show that if $S$ is a countable subset of $\Bbb R$ then the Lebesgue outer measure $m^*(S)=0.$ Second we show that if $J$ is a bounded real interval then $m^*(J)=l(J).$

Now for  $J\subset  \Bbb R$ and for a countable  $S\subset J$ let $A$ be any countable family of open intervals with $\cup A\supset (J \setminus S).$ For $r>0$ let $B_r$ be a countable family of  open intervals with $\cup B_r\supset S$ and $\sum_{b\in B_r}l(b)\leq r.$   Then $C= B_r\cup A$ is a countable family of  open intervals  with $\cup C\supset J$ so   $$m^*(J\setminus S)\leq m^*(J) \leq  \sum_{c\in C}l(c)\leq \sum_{b\in B_r}l(b)+\sum_{a\in A}l(a)\leq r+\sum_{a\in A}l(a).$$ Taking the inf of the right-most  expression above, over every family $A$  of open intervals that covers $J\setminus S,$ we have $$(\bullet ) \quad m^*(J\setminus S)\leq  m^*(J)\leq r+m^*(J \setminus S).$$ Since $(\bullet )$  holds for every $r>0,$ we have  $$m^*(J\setminus S)\leq m^*(J)\leq m^*(J\setminus S).$$ Therefore $m^*(J \setminus  S)=m^*(J).$

In particular if $J$ is a bounded interval then   $m^*(J\setminus S)=m^*(J)=l(J). $

Comment: You should also learn about inner measure. With $m$ denoting Lebesgue measure, the inner measure of any $T\subset \Bbb R$ is $m^i(T)=\sup \{m(U): U=\overline U\subset T\}$..... A set $T\subset \Bbb R$ is Lebesgue-measurable iff $m^*(T)=m^i(T).$

Comment: This answer will apply verbatim for any $S\subset \Bbb R$ such that $m^*(S)=0.$